# would java be able to handle file handling program with 5000 or more files?

Tags: java, file-handling

I want to process large number of files at a go. perl seems to do it very well but am not very much familiar and want to do it with java. would java able to handle? i tried once but java program crashed. what could be the reason..?

Comment: Have you used `exception handling` mechanism?

Comment: if there was an exception, program would have terminated. but my program didnt. it hanged.

Comment: Your are not opening the 5000 files concurrently, but one after the other right? In which case there should not be any issues aside from bugs in your code...

Comment: There is no specific reason on whether Perl would perform better with 6000 files than Java. Please show us some pice of code so we can help you diagnose and fix any issues you'd have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There's no inherent reason that the program would fail when trying to do this, it'll be down to something wrong in your code.

You would need to post your code and details of the error you get for an informed analysis of why it doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure ? like with 6000 or so files..

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening all the files at once and keeping them in memory, there may be a memory problem as JVM has a fixed amount of memory. U can try after increasing  the JVM allocated memory.. Btw, it won't be a good idea to keep all your file in memory. Try to sequentialise ur file reads or use big data methods like hadoop and map reduce to solve ur problem..

Comment: i had arrays which held 50-60 K elements. could that be the reason?

Comment: depends how much memory all of them are taking.. but could be a possibility..